# Extending grid outside the plot - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I have built the following graph[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeAQA.jpg). However, I wish to extend the grid on to show how many `dots` are there in a given power range.

For example: if we assume there are 20 `dots between`5000mW and 10000mW`.

I want it to be represented at the extended grid of `10000mW`. I tried to use the `ax.xaxis.grid` but I don't see a way to extend/protrude the grid outside the plot.

Please let me know if something is not clear.
[image]

I would also love to change the color of the grid.

Comment: @Mods: I would like to put the question up for 50 points bounty. it is an interesting problem, I could not get the answer so far.

Comment: Looks potentially solvable. @pistal, would you want to put up your code so we could take a shot at it?